# Automatically push master on gitlab to a svn repo?

Tags: git, svn, gitlab

I'm thinking about setting up a gitlab server for my organisation.

As there is a central svn-repository where a current snapshot of the projects should also be stored, it would be nice to automate (maybe via a post-receive-hook) pushing the master branch of a project hosted on gitlab to a svn remote.

Is this possible in gitlab? 
Or would this just be messy, and it would be easier to encourage every developer to push to the svn repo by hand? 
Or would automate pulling from gitlab and pushing to svn via a shell script / cronjob be easier?

Thanks for your thoughts on this!

Comment: Jenkins might have this ability, and there's a lot of documentation regarding Gitlab / Jenkins integration

Comment: I actually don't really like to setup yet another system, just to push to SVN. However, if this is the only stable option, I might reconsider. But all I found on this ist the Jenkins SVN Publisher (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SVN+Publisher) which can push artifacts to SVN. Being new to Jenkins, am I correct that an artifact is the result of a build - so this is not what I am looking for?